# django rest framework return selected field in view

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

Let's say I have a model name Book. I have two views(list and detail)

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publishdate = models.DateTimeField()
```

serializers.py

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
```

If I'm going to use this serializer in my list view and detail view. Can I set the return field? Example : list view only return name list only and detail view will return name, author, publishdate field.
Or do I have to create new serializer and insert fields in Class Meta on both class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need different representations for list and detail views you should define seperate serializers for each.  For example...

```
class DetailBookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('name', 'author', 'publishdate')

class ListBookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('name',)
```

Then make sure to set the `serializer_class` attribute as appropriate on each view.

Comment: Thanks Tom for the answer, I thought there was another way :D